# Find and Validate TextBox and DropDown in GridView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Here is my requirement, if textbox value is not null or has a value greater than 0 and the dropdown value is "Select" then i want to show an alert.  My issue now is that the alert is not being fired regardless if the condition is true or not.  What am i doing wrong here? can someone please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
      var flag = true;
      var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= myGridView.ClientID %>');

      for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {

        var dropdowns = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('Select');
        var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        if (dropdowns != null && dropdowns.length > 1 && dropdowns[0] != null && areas != null && areas.length > 1 && areas[1] != null) {
          if (areas[1].type == "textarea" && dropdowns[0].type == "select-one") {
            var txtval = areas[1].value;
            var ddlSelectedItem = dropdowns[0].value;
            if (ddlSelectedItem == "Select" && (txtval != "" || txtval != null || txtval >0)) {


              flag = false;
              break;
            }
            else {
              flag = true;

            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!flag) {
        alert('Please make selection from the dropdown box.  Thanks');

    }
    return flag;
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: that means you have a problem in your loop? place a `debugger;` at the beginning of your function and debug through the console..

Comment: i did.. but i am not able to find the issue.  i have spent several hours on this issue trying to figure out the problem.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my issue by changing textarea to input

```
 var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
```